# Probability: put 20 distinct balls randomly in 12 urns

Tags: probability, combinatorics

You put 20 distinct balls randomly into 12 urns. What is the probability of having 3 urns with 4 balls each and 4 urns with 2 balls each (the other 5 urns are left empty).

For my **sample space** I have: $\frac{(20+12-1)!}{(12-1)!}$ = $\frac{31!}{11!}$

*All possible permutations of 20 distinct balls amongst 12 urns*

For the **event space** I have: ${12 \choose 4}$${20 \choose 2}$${18 \choose 2}$${16 \choose 2}$${14 \choose 2}$${8 \choose 3}$${12 \choose 4}$${8 \choose 4}$${4 \choose 4}$

*Choose 4 urns of 12, then pick 2 balls for each of those, pick 3 more urns from the remaining 8, pick 4 balls for each of these urns.*

This feels pretty wrong to me, and it comes out to a tiny fraction, but I can't get anything else that makes sense to me. Some guidance?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are using a sample space that is very hard to work with. The reason is that not all elements of your sample space are equally likely. It is far easier to assume the balls are distinct (that does not affect the probability, just put ID's in invisible ink on the balls). The best sample space has $12^{20}$ elements.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  Assuming the urns are all distinct (e.g., they are labelled). . .

. . . to count the sample space,

- choose an urn for the first ball. . . . . . $12$ ways
- . . .
- choose an urn for the last ball. . . . . . $12$ ways.

Total number of placements is ???

To count the arrangements that you want,

- choose three urns to take four balls each. . . . . . $C(12,3)$ ways
- choose the balls for the first of these. . . . . . $C(20,4)$ ways
- and for the second. . . . . . $C(16,4)$ ways
- . . . and so on.

See if you can finish this.  Good luck!

Comment: So I've got a sample space of $12^{20}$

and my event space is: $C(12,3)$*$C(20,4)$*$C(16,4)$*$C(12,4)$*$C(9,4)$*$C(8,2)$*$C(6,2)$*$C(4,2)$

Which leaves me with a probability of 0.005%. That seems small to me

Comment: I believe your answer is correct.  To be honest I have no intuitive idea of how large the probability should be, so I wouldn't like to say whether or not it's too small.  I guess you could always try doing a simulation on a computer and see if you get something like $5$ successes out of $1000$ attempts.